# Django/Nginx docker image returning Bad Request (400)

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I followed [this](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) guide to dockerize my django blog, so after I got it running I decided to test it on my VPS. However, as soon as I try to access my app from a browser I get "Bad Request (400)". I've check `lsof -i :1337` to check if the app was listening, at it seems to be working fine.

Here are my configuration files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: gunicorn ASSB.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    expose:
      - 8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream assb {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ASSB;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
    alias /usr/src/app/media/;
    }
}
```

Any idea what could I be doing wrong?

Sorry for the lack of experience, I'm new to docker and nginx, but I still wanted to give it a shot...

Edit:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
edcyjhyhs5df        blog_nginx    "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:1337->80/tcp     blog_nginx_1
84df8nd9f8h0        blog_web      "gunicorn ASSB.wsgi:…"   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   blog_web_1
```

And here's my ALLOWED_HOSTS:
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1", "0.0.0.0"]`

Comment: can you give output of `docker ps` ?

Comment: what exactly are you getting in 400 response? sounds like [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS) is not configured correctly

Comment: can you post on your view?

Comment: Thanks a lot @miki725!, I just added my domain name to the app and it worked!

Comment: Hi @JoseRicardo I followed the same tutorial, tried to adapt it to use a non-dockerized Apache as a proxy pass and experienced a similar 400 error. Could you be a bit more specific concerning where you *added the domain name to the app* to fix your issue?

Comment: Hello @DavidZarebski, sorry for the incredibly late reply, but by that I ment (if I recall correctly, I deleted that app long ago) that I added my server IP to the allowed hosts variable on the django app